# How do I properly format data in a Python POST request to Streamlabs API?

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I'm trying to connect our application to Streamlabs' API so we can post donation alerts. To do that, I need to get an access token for the user whose channel we want to alert on. It's a normal OAuth2 thing. We hit the /authorize endpoint and get a code back, which we're then supposed to able to use to get an access token from the /token endpoint (https://dev.streamlabs.com/v1.0/reference#token-1).

But when we send the POST request for the token, we get an error saying the request is missing the "grant_type" parameter.

We're using the normal requests library. I've tried changing the format of the request to requests.post. I've tried altering the data by wrapping it in urlencode and json.dumps. Still no luck.

```
    streamlabs_client_id = config('STREAMLABS_CLIENT_ID')
    streamlabs_client_secret = config('STREAMLABS_CLIENT_SECRET')
    streamlabs_redirect_uri = config('STREAMLABS_REDIRECT_URI')
    grant_type = 'authorization_code'
    querydict = {
        "grant_type":"authorization_code",
        "client_id":streamlabs_client_id,
        "client_secret":streamlabs_client_secret,
        "redirect_uri":streamlabs_redirect_uri, 
        "code":code
    }
    url = "https://streamlabs.com/api/v1.0/token"
    streamlabs_response = requests.request("POST", url, data=querydict)
```

This is the json I get back every time:

> {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the \"grant_type\" parameter."}

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong with the data?

Comment: You might try HTTP Verb Tampering here. Try converting the `POST` type request to `GET` and see if that works maybe.

Comment: Your request is wrong. This is the correct one

streamlabs_response = requests.request("POST", url, query=querydict)